# Get Autoincrement value after INSERT query in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

```
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr))
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO tblUsers(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, EmailId, Created_Date, typeid) VALUES ('" + ObjUserProp.FirstName + "','" + ObjUserProp.LastName + "','" + ObjUserProp.UserName + "','" + ObjUserProp.Password + "','" + ObjUserProp.EmailId + "','" + ObjUserProp.Created_Date + "'," + ObjUserProp.TypeId + ")", con))
{

    con.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO tblUsersRelation(UserId,usertypeid) VALUES ( LAST_INSERT_ID() ," + ObjUserProp.TypeId + ")", con))
    {
        IsDone = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return IsDone;
    }
}
```

Record is inserted only in 1 table. Please tell me how to take  latest autoincrement ID value.

Answer (score 2):

You are far better off using [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-stored.html), "Routines" as they are referred to in MySql, and passing in input parameters.

Comment: Yes he should be using parameters, but no real need to use a stored procedure or routine. A parameterized query will work all the same.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you want - SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() (from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/getting-unique-id.html).

In essence I'd change the first sql statement to call that after the insert. Then you can pick up the returned value and use it in subsequent sql queries.

That having been said it should work the way you have done it. Though of course I am assuming that you are in fact missing the cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() line. If you really don't have that line then that will be why the second table isn't bein updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(id)
from tblUsers
```

I dont have idea of C#, but I guess this is what u r looking for...

Comment: Using `SELECT MAX(id)` *can* return an incorrect value when one of the records has an id that is greater than the current AUTO_INCREMENT number. I know this is definitely not a common case, but still...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the last inserted id generated by AUTO_INCREMENT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` along with `ExecuteScalar` which will return the record. Using `ExecuteNonQuery` will not return anything.

Aside from your question you also should be using [parameterized queries](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/addparameterizedqueriesinmysqloledb.aspx).