# C# Get insert id with Auto Increment

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql

I am using this method to insert a row into a table:

```
            MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            cmd.Connection = connect;
            cmd.Connection.Open();

            string commandLine = @"INSERT INTO Wanted (clientid,userid,startdate,enddate) VALUES" +
                "(@clientid, @userid, @startdate, @enddate);";
            cmd.CommandText = commandLine;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientid", userId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", "");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", start);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", end);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
```

I hav also id column that have `Auto Increment` .
And i want to know if it possible to get the id that is created when i insert a new row.

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982520/get-autoincrement-value-after-insert-query-in-mysql

Comment: No. i want the id that i am insert

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can access the MySqlCommand LastInsertedId property.

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
```

Comment: Thank you it work!! and if i want to insert multiple row in one insert statement, it is possible to get every id?

Comment: thank you! I read C# hadn't such property so I was writing a method for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = connect;
cmd.Connection.Open();

string commandLine = @"INSERT INTO Wanted (clientid,userid,startdate,enddate) "
    + "VALUES(@clientid, @userid, @startdate, @enddate);";
cmd.CommandText = commandLine;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientid", userId);
**cmd.Parameters["@clientid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;**
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", "");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", start);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", end);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should add this to end of your CommandText:

```
SET @newPK = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

and add another ADO.NET parameter "newPK". After command is executed it will contain new ID.